# RegExp replace innerHTML except if anchor tag or in code tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

my replace function looks like this

```
post.innerHTML = post.innerHTML.replace(treg,function(m){
                  return '<span class="tech-word" title="' + _text[m] + '">' + m + '</span>';
                }).replace(wreg,function(m){
                  return '<a class="post-word-link" href="' + _links[m] + '">' + m + '</a>';    
                }).replace(ireg,function(m){
                  return '<span id="image_'+m+'"><span class="post-hover-img">' + m + '</span><img src="' + _image[m] + '" class="auto-img"></span>';   
                });
```

the regex looks like this

```
wregex=["word1","word2","word3"];
wreg = RegExp('\\b(' + wregex.join('|') + ')\\b(?=\\W)', 'gi');
```

When I do this it works great for words, but it also changes anchor tags as well as code blocks. Anyway to stay away from them by updating the regex or is there something else I am missing.

Comment: [**THE PONY HE COMES**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) You are working in JavaScript. You have NO excuse not to use the DOM for this.

Comment: I got it from that jiberish so basically we can't really look through this. Yet doesn't innerHTML parse out as Text so really it's searching through text. I figured I could use a not regex something like this but the opposite `RegExp('<'+tag+'>(.*?)<\/'+tag+'>','gi')`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I do have an excuse ;) It's a blog/forum and you can't post HTML and so we figured having the Admins have control of this code instead

Comment: @EasyBB: It's not that you *can't* do this in text. It's that doing so is hard, error-prone, full of edge conditions, wipes out event handlers, and unnecessary. Doing it through the DOM is the right way to do it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder please see last comment

Comment: @EasyBB aka, What they are saying is you should not be working with a string, but walking the DOM and getting the text that way. Parsing HTML with a regular expression is a bad bad idea.

Comment: You have `post`, iterate through its child nodes and replace what you want to replace...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol iterating through childNodes is ok I've tried it, not very different from what I had a while back, but the problem persists that nodeType 3 (textNodes) can't be replaced with HTML. Or so I believe as everything I've done comes out as text still.

Comment: @EasyBB Depends how you do it. `someTextNode.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createElement('img'),someTextNode)` works just fine for me!

Comment: ahhh what a freaking goomba I am... totally forgot about that, and it's even in front of my face in the library I wrote like 2 months ago. WOW. Thanks Niet I'll give er a shot. Please take note to answer with this, nice explanation for others who come across.